# Shell Script To Search Paragraphs for a given pattern

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix

I need help with a shell-script which can search an INPUT_FILE for PARAGRAPHS containing a MATCHING PATTERN (In ANY Line of the PARAGRAPH) & produce 2 Output Files:

OUTPUT_FILE_1:: File containing ONLY PARAGRAPHS which do NOT contain the MATCHING PATTERN in any of the Lines

OUTPUT_FILE_2:: File containing ONLY PARAGRAPHS which contains the MATCHING PATTERN in any of the Lines

INPUTS FOR SHELL SCRIPT::
1. INPUT_FILE
2. MATCH_KEY [ Here, MATCH_KEY="**pattern match**" ]

**ASSUMPTION:**

```
All PARAGRAPHS are separated by a BLANK LINE
```

**// INPUT_FILE**

```
first paragraph first line
first paragraph second line
first paragraph third line

second paragraph first line
second paragraph pattern match second line
second paragraph third line

third paragraph first line
third paragraph second line
third paragraph third line

fourth paragraph first line
fourth paragraph second line
fourth paragraph pattern match third line
```

**2 Output Files:**

**// OUTPUT_FILE_1:: contains ONLY Paragraphs WITH MATCHING PATTERN**

```
second paragraph first line
second paragraph pattern match second line
second paragraph third line

fourth paragraph first line
fourth paragraph second line
fourth paragraph pattern match third line
```

**// OUTPUT_FILE_2:: contains ONLY Paragraphs WITHOUT MATCHING PATTERN**

```
first paragraph first line
first paragraph second line
first paragraph third line

third paragraph first line
third paragraph second line
third paragraph third line
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk oneliner:

```
  awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/pattern match/{print > "file1";next}{print >"file2"}' file
```